# Uncaught SyntaxError: Uncexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code throws up an Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpexted identifier on line 3

```
class viewer {

 public viewer() {}

 public void show(int id) {
     $(".previewItem").fadeOut("slow");
     $(".container").append("<img src='../img/portfolio/IMG'" +id +".jpg class='viewerIm'/>");
 }
}
```

I don't understand why, could anyone perhaps let me know?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  Learn about Javascript classes (they don't have access modifiers)

Comment: public void ?? does not sound like javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `public` or `void` keyword in Javascript. Looks like you are mixing different languages.

If you don't want a *class*, but just a single object, your code could look like this:

```
var viewer = {

  show : function (id) {
     $(".previewItem").fadeOut("slow");
     $(".container").append("<img src='../img/portfolio/IMG" +id +".jpg' class='viewerIm'/>");
 }

}
```

Now accessing the functions by class name is done like

```
viewer.show(100);
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder fixed it.. Do you still think its not up to mark?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I changed the comment to say its a object.. Since you already have posted your answer with correct syntax I think I can let this be this way.. or do you think its misguiding

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you so much.. i overlooked it.. Thank you .. really appreciate it.

Comment: I knew it'd be something really stupid, but didn't realise it was that big! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've said you're writing JavaScript and using jQuery, but the code you've posted is **Java**, not JavaScript. (It would even be valid Java if we assume a static import giving you a `$` method.) They're completely different (though superficially-similar) languages.

I suggest reading up on JavaScript.

If you really want a class (e.g., you'll be creating multiple instances), keep reading; if not, if you wanted just a single `viewer` object, see [Rajshekar Reddy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41209745/157247).

To create a class in modern (ES2015 and later) JavaScript, your code is largely correct if we just remove `public` and `int` and change the definition of the constructor:

```
// ES2015+
class viewer {

    constructor() {}

    void show(id) {
        $(".previewItem").fadeOut("slow");
        $(".container").append("<img src='../img/portfolio/IMG'" +id +".jpg class='viewerIm'/>");
    }
}
```

But note that there are still a lot of browsers out there that can't handle ES2015's `class` syntax yet.

In ES5, it would be like this:

```
// ES5 and earlier
function viewer() {
}
viewer.prototype.show = function show(id) {
    $(".previewItem").fadeOut("slow");
    $(".container").append("<img src='../img/portfolio/IMG'" +id +".jpg class='viewerIm'/>");
};
```

---

And note that in both cases (and in Java, and in C#), the overwhelming convention is to name a class with a capital first letter, e.g. `Viewer`, not `viewer`.